Mi código para gráficar funciona perfectamente con números positivos pero no con negativos
me gustaría saber si alguien podria decirme cual es el error.
mi código es para aplicar a una gráfica de barras apiladas una condiciónal en las etiquetas que dice:
si el valor de clase es mayor que 40 o menos que -40 entonces que aparezca la etiqueta, si es menor que 40 o mayor a -40 que no aparezca.
él problema es que las etiquetas mostraban los datos de manera desordenada y ya que cada clase tiene un color específico que lo representa en la gráfica decidí atar la etiqueta a un determinado color en la gráfica, hice 2 graficas mas con este codigo y funciona perfecto pero en la tercera grafica por tener valores negativos no funciona y las etiquetas que se vuelven locas son las de los valores positivos, soy nueva en el uso de Python asi que no se si es algo que pueda estar pasando por alto o que puedo hacer para corregir este error.
les dejo mi código por si alguien puede ayudarme.
Saludos.
Nota: este es solo el fragmento que falla en el código completo de la gráfica
def addlabels_demases (x, y, bottoms, color):

estilo_demases = {

'fontsize': 10,

'fontweight': 'bold',

'color': 'white'

}

for i in range(len(x)):

# Solo agregar etiquetas si el valor absoluto es mayor a 40

if abs(y[i]) > 40:

# Colocar La etiqueta en el centro del segmento

y_position = bottoms[i] + (y[i] / 2)

plt.text(i, y_position,

"{:.0f}".format(round (y[i])),

ha="center",

va='center',

**estilo_demases)

# Colores para Las barras

colors = [

'#D7C977'# FX

*#002060'# Cash

*#5D2884'#UMS

'#502884'#Corporativos

'#FF4B21'#RV Intern

'#FFC000'#RV Na

'#663300'# Fibras

'#008050'# KND

'#007000'# Nomina

'#007000'# Deuda

'#00BØFO'# Reales
]

# Inicializar el "fondo" de cada barra apilada en bottoms 

bottoms = [0] len(datos_pivot.index)

# Agregar etiquetas a La gráfica existente 

for col, color in zip(datos_pivot.columns[:-1], colors): addlabels_demases (datos_pivot.index, datos_pivot.values, bottoms, color) bottoms = [bottoms [i] + datos_pivot.values[i] for i in range(len(bottoms))]


si alguien puede ayudarme y necesita que suba el código de mi gráfica completo porfavor dígamelo, se los agradecía mucho

Te dejo el código modificado:


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def addlabels_demases(x, y, bottoms):
    estilo_demases = {
        'fontsize': 10,
        'fontweight': 'bold',
        'color': 'white'
    }
    
    for i in range(len(x)):
        # Solo agregar etiquetas si el valor absoluto es mayor a 40
        if abs(y[i]) > 40:
            # Colocar la etiqueta en el centro del segmento
            y_position = bottoms[i] + (y[i] / 2)
            plt.text(i, y_position,
                     "{:.0f}".format(round(y[i])),
                     ha="center",
                     va='center',
                     **estilo_demases)

# acá los colores para las barras
colors = [
    '#D7C977',  # FX
    '#002060',  # Cash
    '#5D2884',  # UMS
    '#502884',  # Corporativos
    '#FF4B21',  # RV Intern
    '#FFC000',  # RV Na
    '#663300',  # Fibras
    '#008050',  # KND
    '#007000',  # Nomina
    '#00B0F0',  # Reales
]

# el fondo
bottoms = [0] * len(datos_pivot.index)

# etiquetas 
for col, color in zip(datos_pivot.columns[:-1], colors):
    # Suponiendo que `datos_pivot` tiene las columnas adecuadas
    values = datos_pivot[col].values  # Obtén los valores de la columna actual
    addlabels_demases(datos_pivot.index, values, bottoms)
    
    # Actualiza
    bottoms = [bottoms[i] + values[i] for i in range(len(bottoms))]

# la gráfica
plt.show()



No era necesario pasar el color a la función, ya que no lo utilizas dentro de ella. La función ahora solo recibe x, y, y bottoms. En tu bucle principal, fijate de estar pasando los valores correctos a addlabels_demases.
datos_pivot[col].values se refiere a los valores de la columna actual.
Empece bottoms correctamente con ceros y la lógica para actualizar bottoms despues de añadir las etiquetas se mantiene intacta.
Si los valores negativos siguen con errores en la posición de las etiquetas podes ajustar la lógica de y_position para asegurarte de que siempre se muestren en el lugar correcto.
Si estas utilizando barras apiladas y queres que las etiquetas se coloquen dentro de las barras, tenes que ver que se coloquen en la parte adecuada. Podes considerar añadir y[i] / 2 a bottoms[i].
Saludos.
